# Is it secure to have database login in a PHP file? Other options?

Tags: mysql, security, php

I'm a DB and SQL beginner. I'm putting together a basic PHP app that has a few SQL queries. In all my searching and learning, every example accessed the database by first logging in. Makes sense, but in PHP, you have to put these credentials right in the PHP file, like this:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","db");
```

This seems risky. For example, I'm aware of some server faults that will show your php file's text instead of executing.

Is this the kind of thing that beginners are shown for ease of access? If yes, what's the better way? Or is this standard and there's really not much to worry about? Why is it not a security hole?

Comment: I found [tag:row-level-security] which is neat, but not the same it seems.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. I think this question is more of a programming issue than a database issue. Your question might be better suited over on Stack Overflow. The answer to the question [Why mysqli_connect() must receive the password parameter with no encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46897705/1820861) might be a good starting point. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I have done for PHP projects is to define the database credentials (or any other credentials, for example web services) in files outside the http document root.

In fact, most of your code can and should be put outside the http document root.

Then if your http server becomes misconfigured somehow and starts serving PHP code instead of executing the PHP code, then all they will see is:

```
<?php

include "myconfig.php";
include "myapp.php";
```

Comment: I think I came across this for different security reasons, recently. Basically, I can just put all these sensitive materials in private_html and include at the top of index.php?

Comment: Yeah, it was a page suggesting to move wp_config outside of the public root. I've implemented such a solution now. Makes be feel better, but I don't actually know if this matters. A lot of people say it does, but some argue it doesn't. I'm giving you the selection for now, but invite other answers to attempt a steal.

Comment: Certainly there are ways to reduce the risk. Be careful not to let your http server lose its configuration for the PHP handler, for example. One could claim that "should" never happen.

Answer (score 1):

The other common choice is to server a web page, and then the user manually enters the username and password and submits it back through the php script.

Comment: That would require a login for every script run. Certainly can't do that for customers, but if I'm paranoid enough about a private app, might endure it for myself. +1 for the thought.

Comment: You can store the credentials in a session, and pass them from script to script.  So if you had some kind of main menu the user would login to the main menu, and you would pass the credential to each script internally.  Then when the user clicks "Logout" or whatever you name it, the session is destroyed along with the stored credentials.